# combination of keycode of in unix environment

Tags: linux, keyboard, key-bindings, keycode

I found the [keycode in deeps](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.pdf).

But I need a table to completed list of combination keycode such as :

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> == KEYCODE ie. 0174

ALT and SHITF are two types: Right and Left.

You can help me 3 kinds:

- Guide me how to write a program to retrive all of them
- Introduce me useful link
- Introduce me a sample application to work me.

Comment: Try `man showkey` For Fedora, that ships with the `kbd` package.

Comment: You can post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU/Linux has

```
showkey
```

it ships with package `kbd` in Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'
```